# How to run program on Atom using python?

Tags: python, atom-editor

i'm trying to use atom text editor to run a python code but when i type in any command, it doesn't show up on my terminal, i'm using windows 10, here is an example of what happens:
i've download scrpit and terminal-ide but it still doesn't work, i'm new to this it's my first time ever using atom and i'm just 16, i just dont know what's the problem
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to install package called [script](https://atom.io/packages/script) or [hydrogen](https://atom.io/packages/hydrogen)

Comment: hey thank u, i have downloaded script it still doesn't work

Comment: To do that you can simply press Ctrl+Shift+P and search for "run" or you can directly press Ctrl+B.
You may want to configure the version of python to run your script, simply press Ctrl+Shift+P and search for "script run options" and select it from the drop down menu, in the "Command" field write "python3" or any other version you need, leave all the others fields blank, finally click on "Save as profile" and enter a name for the profile.
Now when you want run your script with a specific version pres Ctrl+Shift+P search for "Run with profile" click and choose the previously saved profile.

Comment: I recommend for hydrogen for better debugging

Comment: Then verify for me the solution and upvote so that others can find my answer